# Simplifying a piece of code that switches classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have the following piece of code that is placed in a render function. The function runs few times per second.

```
if ($play.hasClass(playClass)){
   $play.removeClass("playing paused").addClass(playClass);

}else{
   $play.removeClass("playing paused").addClass(playClass);
}
```

I want to make sure the code only runs if the playClass is does not exist in the `$play` element. if it does. Removes all classes and add the current version of playClass.
This is somehow what toggleClass does, but the difference is, since my codes runs few times per second, the toggleclass will keep changing the class.

What I want to achieve is that if the value of `playClass` does not exist in `$play`, then swap it with the previous one and only do it when it is different. Do not check it every time.

The value of `$play` can be either `playing` or `paused`.

This code is doing the job correctly, I just want to find out if there is a more efficient and professional way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't have other classes in this element, In vanilla you can replace all your classes using `.className=""`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any ' if ' because they do the same.
just:

```
$play.removeClass("playing paused").addClass(playClass);
```